# Exit Particular member/owner from Groupchat/Room using XMPP in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework, node-xmpp

Currently i am making chat application.

I will implement Group chat exit same like Whats app.

For example,
I am group owner and after some time i will leave from Group.After i leaving from group any one member of the Group assign as a Group owner.

For that i applied following code :

1st fetch all members in the groupchat and then all members left groupchat manually but it also not working.

```
NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"];

NSXMLElement *item = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"item"];

[item addAttributeWithName:@"affiliation" stringValue:@"member"];

[item addAttributeWithName:@"jid" stringValue:@"jid to remove"];

[query addChild:item];

XMPPIQ *RemoveUser = [[XMPPIQ alloc] initWithType:@"set" to:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",dialuser2,kSIPDomain]] elementID:@"some random id" child:query];

[SharedAppDelegate.xmppStream sendElement:RemoveUser];
```

so any one have code or related information then please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the `affiliation` to **`owner`** but not `member`.

As [Xmpp Owner Usecases](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#owner), [Xmpp Admin Usecases](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#admin) describe (Notice the values of `affiliation`):

- To promote a user as owner:

`<iq from='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    id='owner1'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='set'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
    <item affiliation='owner'
          jid='hecate@shakespeare.lit'>
      <reason>A worthy witch indeed!</reason>
    </item>
  </query>
</iq>`

- To revoke a membership

`<iq from='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
    id='member2'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='set'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
    <item affiliation='none'
          jid='hag66@shakespeare.lit'>
      <reason>Not so worthy after all!</reason>
    </item>
  </query>
</iq>`

- To ban a user

`<iq from='kinghenryv@shakespeare.lit/throne' id='ban1' to='southampton@chat.shakespeare.lit' type='set'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
    <item affiliation='outcast'
          jid='earlofcambridge@shakespeare.lit'>
      <reason>Treason</reason>
    </item>
  </query>
</iq>`

Comment: yes, it's working if I am the admin of that group, but if I am not admin for that group and want to remove or exit from the group then how i can do it ?

Comment: @KaushikMovaliya did you find solution for your problem? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: No @nikBhosale , not yet